# Как получить contact в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Не получается заполучить данные о контакте, которые отправляются пользователем.

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Person.age)
async def get_age(msg: types.Message):
    if func.check_age_sym(msg.text):
        if func.check_age(int(msg.text)):
            keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить номер телефона ", request_contact=True))

            await msg.answer("Отправь свой контакт:", reply_markup=keyboard)
            await Person.contact.set()
    else:
        await msg.answer(emoji.emojize(config.text['err_age']), parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
        return


@dp.message_handler(state=Person.contact)
async def contacts(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await msg.answer(f"Твой номер успешно получен: {msg.contact.phone_number}", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    await state.finish()
```

У меня ничего не происходит, когда отправляю контакт. Что не так с кодом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в хендлере ловить конкретный тип апдейта

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.CONTACT, state=Person.contact)
async def contacts(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await msg.answer(f"Твой номер успешно получен: {msg.contact.phone_number}", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    await state.finish()
```